Get cell tower data
How to get cell tower data to which a SIM card is connected on Android 10?
I tried several options and none of them worked. All rights are granted (Permission.INTERNET, Permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Permission.READ_PHONE_STATE). Location (geolacing) is enabled. But the for cell_info in cell_info_list loop is not executed
from kivy.app import App

if (platform == 'android'):
    import android
    from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
    from jnius import autoclass, cast

    request_permissions([
        Permission.INTERNET,
        Permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
        Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
        Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
        Permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,
    ])

def get_cell_location():
    try:
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        android_context = PythonActivity.mActivity

        TelephonyManager = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager')
        tel_manager = cast('android.telephony.TelephonyManager',
                           android_context.getSystemService(android_context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE))

        cell_info_list = tel_manager.getAllCellInfo()

        for cell_info in cell_info_list:
            if isinstance(cell_info, autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoGsm')):
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM
            elif isinstance(cell_info, autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoCdma')):
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getSystemId()
                mnc = cell_identity.getNetworkId()
                lac = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                cid = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
            elif isinstance(cell_info, autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoLte')):
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCi()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE
            elif isinstance(cell_info, autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma')):
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
            elif isinstance(cell_info, autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoNr')):
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getNci()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR
            else:
                mcc = ""
                mnc = ""
                lac = ""
                cid = ""
                network_type = ""
                continue

            print(f"{mcc}\n{mnc}\n{lac}\n{cid}\n{str(network_type)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)

    def build(self):
        get_cell_location()
        return self.screen

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()

further options for the function of receiving
def get_cell_location():
    try:
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        android_context = PythonActivity.mActivity

        TelephonyManager = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager')
        tel_manager = cast('android.telephony.TelephonyManager',
                           android_context.getSystemService(android_context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE))

        cell_info_list = tel_manager.getAllCellInfo()

        for cell_info in cell_info_list:
            cell_type = cell_info.get_cell_type()
            if cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfo$CellType').GSM:
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc(),
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager').NETWORK_TYPE_GSM
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfo$CellType').CDMA:
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getSystemId()
                mnc = cell_identity.getNetworkId()
                lac = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                cid = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                network_type = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager').NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfo$CellType').LTE:
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCi()
                network_type = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager').NETWORK_TYPE_LTE
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfo$CellType').WCDMA:
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager').NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfo$CellType').NR:
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getNci()
                network_type = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager').NETWORK_TYPE_NR
            else:
                mcc = ""
                mnc = ""
                lac = ""
                cid = ""
                network_type = ""
                continue

            print(f"{mcc}\n{mnc}\n{lac}\n{cid}\n{str(network_type)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

def get_cell_location():
    try:
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        android_context = PythonActivity.mActivity

        TelephonyManager = autoclass('android.telephony.TelephonyManager')
        tel_manager = cast('android.telephony.TelephonyManager',
                           android_context.getSystemService(android_context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE))

        cell_info_list = tel_manager.getAllCellInfo()

        for cell_info in cell_info_list:
            cell_type = cell_info.getClass().getSimpleName()
            if cell_type == "CellInfoGsm":
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM
            elif cell_type == "CellInfoCdma":
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getSystemId()
                mnc = cell_identity.getNetworkId()
                lac = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                cid = cell_identity.getBasestationId()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
            elif cell_type == "CellInfoLte":
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCi()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE
            elif cell_type == "CellInfoWcdma":
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMcc()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMnc()
                lac = cell_identity.getLac()
                cid = cell_identity.getCid()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
            elif cell_type == "CellInfoNr":
                cell_identity = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cell_identity.getMccString()
                mnc = cell_identity.getMncString()
                lac = cell_identity.getTac()
                cid = cell_identity.getNci()
                network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR
            else:
                mcc = ""
                mnc = ""
                lac = ""
                cid = ""
                network_type = ""
                continue

            print(f"{mcc}\n{mnc}\n{lac}\n{cid}\n{str(network_type)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

def get_cell_location():
    try:
        service_state = tel_manager.getServiceState()
        cell_location = tel_manager.getCellLocation()

        if isinstance(cell_location, autoclass('android.telephony.gsm.GsmCellLocation')):
            gsm_cell_location = cell_location
            mcc = gsm_cell_location.getMobileCountryCode()
            mnc = gsm_cell_location.getMobileNetworkCode()
            lac = gsm_cell_location.getLac()
            cid = gsm_cell_location.getCid()
            network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_GSM
        elif isinstance(cell_location, autoclass('android.telephony.cdma.CdmaCellLocation')):
            cdma_cell_location = cell_location
            mcc = service_state.getSystemId()
            mnc = service_state.getNetworkId()
            lac = cdma_cell_location.getBaseStationId()
            cid = cdma_cell_location.getBaseStationId()
            network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_CDMA
        elif isinstance(cell_location, autoclass('android.telephony.CellIdentityLte')):
            lte_cell_identity = cell_location
            mcc = lte_cell_identity.getMccString()
            mnc = lte_cell_identity.getMncString()
            lac = lte_cell_identity.getTac()
            cid = lte_cell_identity.getCi()
            network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_LTE
        elif isinstance(cell_location, autoclass('android.telephony.CellIdentityWcdma')):
            wcdma_cell_identity = cell_location
            mcc = wcdma_cell_identity.getMcc()
            mnc = wcdma_cell_identity.getMnc()
            lac = wcdma_cell_identity.getLac()
            cid = wcdma_cell_identity.getCid()
            network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_UMTS
        elif isinstance(cell_location, autoclass('android.telephony.CellIdentityLte')):
            nr_cell_identity = cell_location
            mcc = nr_cell_identity.getMccString()
            mnc = nr_cell_identity.getMncString()
            lac = nr_cell_identity.getTac()
            cid = nr_cell_identity.getNCi()
            network_type = TelephonyManager.NETWORK_TYPE_NR
        else:
            mcc = ""
            mnc = ""
            lac = ""
            cid = ""
            network_type = ""
            continue

        print(f"{mcc}\n{mnc}\n{lac}\n{cid}\n{str(network_type)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

def get_cell_location():
    try:
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
        android_context = PythonActivity.mActivity

        cell_info_manager = cast('android.telephony.CellInfoManager', android_context.getSystemService(android_context.CELL_INFO_SERVICE))


        # Or try instead of the first lines
        # android_context = android_activity.get_context()
        # cell_info_manager = cast('android.telephony.CellInfoManager', context.getSystemService(context.CELL_INFO_SERVICE))

        cell_info_list = cell_info_manager.getCellInfo()
        print(len(cell_info_list))

        for cell_info in cell_info_list:
            cell_type = type(cell_info)

            if cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoGsm'):
                gsm_cell_info = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = gsm_cell_info.getMcc()
                mnc = gsm_cell_info.getMnc()
                lac = gsm_cell_info.getLac()
                cid = gsm_cell_info.getCid()
                network_type = 'GSM'
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoCdma'):
                cdma_cell_info = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = cdma_cell_info.getSystemId()
                mnc = cdma_cell_info.getNetworkId()
                lac = cdma_cell_info.getBasestationId()
                cid = cdma_cell_info.getBasestationId()
                network_type = 'CDMA'
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoLte'):
                lte_cell_info = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = lte_cell_info.getMccString()
                mnc = lte_cell_info.getMncString()
                lac = lte_cell_info.getTac()
                cid = lte_cell_info.getCi()
                network_type = 'LTE'
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoWcdma'):
                wcdma_cell_info = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = wcdma_cell_info.getMcc()
                mnc = wcdma_cell_info.getMnc()
                lac = wcdma_cell_info.getLac()
                cid = wcdma_cell_info.getCid()
                network_type = 'WCDMA'
            elif cell_type == autoclass('android.telephony.CellInfoNr'):
                nr_cell_info = cell_info.getCellIdentity()
                mcc = nr_cell_info.getMccString()
                mnc = nr_cell_info.getMncString()
                lac = nr_cell_info.getTac()
                cid = nr_cell_info.getNci()
                network_type = 'NR'
            else:
                mcc = ""
                mnc = ""
                lac = ""
                cid = ""
                network_type = ""
                continue

            print(f"{mcc}\n{mnc}\n{lac}\n{cid}\n{str(network_type)}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))

I read the android documentation. Since version 10, you need to call a callback, but due to lack of knowledge, I don’t know how to implement this.
UPD:
I also have the data update for towers disabled in the engineering menu. Enabling it didn't change anything. But from the documentation, you need to somehow implement a request for an update and then a callback

"you need to call a callback" That's not how callbacks work. They are functions that are registered to be called (automatically) when something happens.

@KlausD. I understand. Help me implement it correctly.
